# How to sort a list based on a IO Int value

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a `[(String, [String], IO Int)]` list, which I'd like to sort. `sortBy (\x -> ...) list` requires me to use IO to fetch the internal value of the `IO Int`, which means that I can't return `Ordering` but only `IO Ordering` to the `sortBy` function. Is there any way to sort the list?

Comment: If your comparison function is in `IO`, that means the comparison can change each time you do it.  How can you sort a list if you can't reproducibly compare two elements?

Comment: I think we are talking to abstractly here. How would you do what you want to do in a conventional language like Python or Java or Javascript?

Comment: Why can't you run the `IO` action, get the `Int`, then sort the list?  Are you really wanting to get a potentially different `Int` every time you compare an element of the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third element of each tuple is `IO Int`, so its value depends on the external world. So the *order* of the sorted list depends on the external world. So no, there's no way to make a  `[(String, [String], IO Int)]` that is sorted by the value of the `IO Int`.

What you *can* do is make a value of `IO [(String, [String], Int)]`, and then lift the `sortBy` function *into* the `IO` monad to give you another `IO [(String, [String], Int)]` that will yield a list sorted by the `Int`. That isn't a pure list, but you can inject lift any other pure function into the `IO` monad to do arbitrary pure computations on it.

Something like this would do:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List

l :: [(String, [String], IO Int)]
l = [("Foo", [], return 2), ("Bar", [], return 1)]

f :: Monad m => (a, b, m c) -> m (a, b, c)
f (x, y, ioz) = ioz >>= \z -> return (x, y, z)

sl = sortBy (\(x, y, z) (x', y', z') -> compare z z') <$> mapM f l
```

I should mention, since it might not be obvious, that this will run the `IO Int` actions in the order in which they appeared in the list originally. But to sort them you have to run them to get the `Int` values, and they have to be run in *some* order.

Comment: @Witiko That's generally how I strive to program in Haskell. Write all the computation as pure functions. At some point your computation depends on `IO` values, but you try to lift pure functions into the `IO` monad to do all the real work ASAP. That means you get to do most of your work as if `IO` didn't exist, and even when you're writing `IO` code you're hopefully just lifting pure functions and wiring up the results, rather than re-implementing `IO` versions of things.